# how can I measure a surface of a circle with input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone tell me everything wrong with my code?

```js
const PI = 3.14;

function povrsina(r) {
  if (!null) {
    return (r * r) * PI;
  }
}

function prikazivanje(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var poluP = document.getElementById("broj");
  var poluP2 = poluP.value;
  var r = parseFloat(poluP2);
  var povrsina = povrsina(r);
  var rezultat = document.getElementById("rezultat");
  rezultat.innerHTML = povrsina;
}

var dugme = document.getElementById("izracunaj");
dugme.addEventListener("click", prikazivanje);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Povrsina kruga</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body style="background-color: #DDDDDD">
  <header>
    <div style="background-color: silver; text-align: center">
      <h1>Povrsina kruga</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <form style="text-align: center">
      <label for="broj">Unesi poluprecnik</label>
      <input type="text" id="broj" />
      <button id="izracunaj">Izracunaj</button>
    </form>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">
      Resenje: <span id="rezultat"></span>
    </h1>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

When the button is clicked, if the input is null I don't want anything to happen, but if it has a number I want the answer to be right next to "Resenje: "

Comment: From the console: `"Uncaught TypeError: povrsina is not a function"` which points to `var povrsina = povrsina(r);`  <-- your issue, variable name is same as function....

Comment: Also `if (!null)` will always be true and execute what is inside. You probably want `if (r != undefined)`

Comment: It's understandable why this is confusing. You might thing the right-side is evaluated first and then assigned to the left, but the variable declaration gets hoisted so `povrsina` is undefined at the start of the function.

Comment: Side note: JS had a built in constant for PI, `Math.PI`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var povrsina = povrsina(r);
```

In line 54, name your variable something different. The error is being created because your variable name is being used as a function as well.

```
if(!null) {
    return (r * r) * PI;
}
```

You should also change your if statement to something like if(r != undefined){...}.